# MySql query incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'

Tags: mysql

It's a simple SQL query but it keep on giving me this error error incorrect syntax near keyword 'Order'

My Query :

```
select * from Order;
```

Comment: `ORDER` is a reserved word: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html  If you need to name tables/columns/etc. the same as reserved words, you have to surround them with back-ticks (in MySQL) to specify they are identifiers.

Comment: Changed My Table name to Orders and it Sort out my problem Thanks @David

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`Order\`;`

Comment: @David Please do not write answers in the comments section. That's what the answer section is for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a reserved word in the language to represent an entity you created.
Reserved word = a word that is actually part of the vocabulary of the language, for example `select` `FROM` `WHERE` etc.
This makes the compiler/parser confused. To tell the compiler/parser to regard the reserved word as a user selected name (like the name you chose for a field or a table), put back ticks around it. Like so:

```
   select * from `ORDER`
```

Comment: In fact, you should just get into the habit of always using backticks for field names like this.

Answer (score 2):

"Order" is a reserved word. Like trying to name a column "String". Try using another name, something like "Order_Of_Something"